# Source Page with IPA symbols

Tags: c#

How do I get the source code of a website containing IPA symbols?

IPA = Phonetic symbols

**The following code does not work for these characters:**

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

**EDIT:**

The above code display `?d'm?t`

and should display `ədˈmɪt`

Comment: Please explain what “does not work” means here. Also are the symbols written in Unicode on the page?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added information in the post

Comment: how is the encoding done on the response?

Comment: You don't need to *force* the encoding, WebClient will read whatever encoding the *server* sends. If you get `?` it means the encoding was wrong. Given that you tried to *force* the encoding, that's probably the reason

Comment: @Imposoft SO is an ASP.NET site on top of a SQL Server database. The symbols you posted display just fine without you having to do anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When I set the default encoding, I get `ÉtdË?mÉŞt`

Comment: *Don't* set *any* encoding. That will let `WebClient` use the *response's* encoding to read the data and return a string. The fact that you can write and read `ədˈmɪt` in this page means you *don't* need to do anything to read Unicode pages. Try it. Just type `client.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768231/source-page-with-ipa-symbols")`. You should be able to retrieve the IPA symbols without problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The point is that I removed the line of code responsible for the Encoding setting and obtained the result as above, I added

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos From this page also returns `ÉtdË?mÉŞt`. Without encoding set. At first, I thought that maybe the page is blocking the reading but on the other it is the same

Comment: @Imposoft what I get in LinqPad is `É™dËˆmÉªt`. Looks like LInqPad displays the UTF8 *bytes*. How did you check your text? The console *won't* display UTF8 text unless you set it to do so

Comment: what is the response encoding header set to?

Comment: Fiddler displays `ədˈmɪt`. `response.Contains("ədˈmɪt")` returns *false* though!

Comment: @DanielA.White the code for *this* page is UTF8, Fiddler shows ədˈmɪt and yet the response string doesn't contain that string, it contains É™dËˆmÉªt .There's definitely something going on here

Comment: Problem solved. The error was in displaying the result. Visual Studio does not support these characters in the console. At least in my case

Comment: @Imposoft definitely not in the *console*, not without setting `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`. The weird thing is that *Linqpad* has the same issue. It's even weirder that `Contains` doesn't return true